# A problema about gamma distribution and convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

How can I solve this problem?

> Let $Y_{n}\sim \textbf{Gamma}(n,1)$, $n\geq 1$. Prove that $$\frac{Y_{n}-n}{\sqrt{Y_{n}}}\overset{D}{\to}N(0,1)$$
> **My approach:** First I think that since $Y_{n}$ is a sample so I can suppose that $Y_{i}$, $i=1,\ldots, n$ are independent random variables. Now, I think I need to prove that $Y_{n}-n \overset{D}{\to} N(0,1)$ also $\sqrt{Y_n} \overset{D}{\to} 1$. So, by Slutsky' theorem we can conclude that $\frac{Y_{n}-n}{\sqrt{Y_{n}}}\overset{D}{\to} N(0,1)$.

But, can I continue from here? I think the central limit theorem is helful , but I don't know how to use the central limit theorem in this problem.

Comment: are you sure that the denominator is what you wrote and not $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Yes, I'm  sure that the denominator is $ \sqrt{Y_{n}}$

Comment: $\sqrt{X_n}$ ??

Comment: The problem state that "Prove that if $Y_{n}\sim Gamma(n,1), n\geq 1 \implies \frac{Y_{n}-n}{\sqrt{Y_n}}\overset{D}{\to} N(0,1)$.

Comment: I don't sure if the statement is incorrect. I have found almost no typos in the text I am studying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that $Y_n=\Sigma_n X_n$ where $X_n\sim Exp(1)$, thus $E(X_i)=V(X_i)=1$

then re-write your sequence in the following way

$$\frac{\Sigma_n X_n-n}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{n}{\Sigma_n X_n}}=A\times \sqrt{B}$$

Now, $A\xrightarrow{d}N(0;1)$ because it is exactly the defintion of CLT.

Note also that $B=\frac{1}{\overline{X}_n}$ and thus, by Law of Large Numbers and Continuous mapping theorem, $\sqrt{B}\xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}}1$

Finally apply Slutsky  to conclude your proof.

---

$\sqrt{n}$ is needed in the denominator...that was the aim of my question before: if you have not it...get it re-writing your sequence!

Comment: Oh! I understand I think the key ideas is that $Y_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}, X_{i}\sim Exp(1)$. I was just trying use the central limit theorem but I didn't know how get the form you ask to demonstrate. Than you so much @tommik.